# Cómo conseguir UUID o MAC Address en iOS y Android?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Buenas a todos,
recientemente estoy desarrollando apps nativas en iOS y Android que manejan dispositivos Bluetooth BLE.

Para iOS utilizo **CoreBluetooth** y para Android **BluetoothDevice**

Al encontrar el dispositivo BLE, se puede referenciar en Android mediante la MAC Address, y en iOS mediante el UUID del dispositivo.

Las tramas de ejemplo que devuelven para el mismo dispositivo son las siguientes:

**iOS**

```
    
    CBPeripheral: 0x1700ff880, 
    identifier = A3D26155-414C-4940-8EB9-C754AD202B64, //UUID
    name = DEVICE01,
    state = disconnected
```

**Android**

```
    
    mDevice=00:18:31:84:37:E5, //MAC ADDRESS
    mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6,
    mServiceUuids=[0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb],
    mManufacturerSpecificData={}, mServiceData={},
    mTxPowerLevel=-2147483648, mDeviceName=DEVICE01],
    mRssi=-58,
    mTimestampNanos=5196365700642
```

El problema es que no puedo reconocer el mismo dispositivo entre las dos plataformas, ya que en iOS el identificador es el UUID, y en Android la MAC ADDRESS.

He estado buscando como acceder a la MAC ADDRESS en iOS y dicen que no está permitido por temas de seguridad, mientras que el UUID en Android no hay un valor similar al de iOS.

Existe la posibilidad de acceder de alguna manera a algún dato común entre los dos?

***NOTA:** Aclaro que el nombre del dispositivo se repite en todos los dispositivos y no es una variable a tener en cuenta como identificador.*

Muchas gracias!

Comment: No es posible tener la MAC ADDRESS desde IOS ni el UUID desde android, para identificar el dispositivo de cada usuario te recomiendo que tu hagas un ID interno basado en el usuario y en la MAC o el UUID.

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, no se puede. iOS tan sólo te da el UDID. Nosotros en un proyecto lo hemos solucionado metiendo la Mac en el CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey del dispositivo. De esa manera, desde la app, cuando encuentras un peripheral, miras esa info de manufacturer y lees la Mac.